# Removing element white space inside v-layout [Vue + Vuetify]

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I wanted to make a stepper display for forms at the top and I can't seem to figure out why is there a white space or rather why is the last spacing for the `v-divider` shown even with `v-if` in place. I'm using Vue + Vuetify 1.2

[image]

This is how my template looks like

```
<v-layout row style="padding: 25px 0;">
    <v-layout align-center v-for="(item, index) in stepperInfo" v-bind:key="index">
        <div class="ml-4 mr-4 caption">
            <v-layout class="mb-1">
              <v-icon small style="margin: auto;">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-layout>
            {{ item.title }}
        </div>
        <v-divider v-if="index !== stepperInfo.length - 1"></v-divider>
    </v-layout>
</v-layout>
```

And for the data, I just have this:

```
stepperInfo: [
            {
                icon: 'fa-building',
                title: 'Step 1'
            },
            {
                icon: 'fa-briefcase',
                title: 'Step 2'
            },
            {
                icon: 'fa-clipboard-list',
                title: 'Step 3'
            },
            {
                icon: 'fa-file-invoice-dollar',
                title: 'Step 4'
            },
            {
                icon: 'fa-users',
                title: 'Step 5'
            }
        ]
```

Comment: `v-layout` is `flex:1 1 auto`, each of five take 20% width for one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, `v-layout` applies the `flex: 1 1 auto` style to each element/step. The first value for the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) shorthand property is [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), which when set to 1 means the element will expand to fill all available space. This means that the container for your last step is occupying 1/5th (for 5 steps) of the available width. Since the contents of your last step only contains a left-aligned icon/text you get the appearance of white space at the end. A simple approach would be to stop your last step from growing and thereby taking up an equal width to the other steps.

I couldn't find a way to control the `flex-grow` property using props provided by Veutify, but you can override the property yourself on each step like so:

```
<v-layout align-center v-for="(item, index) in stepperInfo" v-bind:key="index" v-bind:style="{'flex-grow': index === (stepperInfo.length - 1) ? 0 : 1}">
```

However this will unnecessarily apply `flex-grow: 1` to all steps except the last. There are a few ways to clean this up, such as moving `flex-grow: 0` to a `last-step` class which is only applied to the last step, as demonstrated in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdBrXz):

```
<v-layout align-center v-for="(item, index) in stepperInfo" v-bind:key="index" v-bind:class="{'last-step': index === (stepperInfo.length - 1)}">
```

You could also use the `:last-child` CSS selector for a CSS only approach as demonstrated in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdjVQX). Apply a `steps` class to the parent `v-layout`:

```
<v-layout row style="padding: 25px 0;" class="steps">
```

And add the following CSS to set `flex-grow: 0` on the last immediate child of a `.steps` element:

```
.steps >:last-child {
  flex-grow: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tomhah & Sphinx! Didn't realize that it was because of the flex attributes - thanks for pointing that out! I got the result I needed by applying `flex-grow: 0` to the last v-divider.